# max float represented in IEEE 754

Tags: floating-point, computer-science, ieee-754

I am wondering if the max float represented in IEEE 754 is:

`(1.11111111111111111111111)_b*2^[(11111111)_b-127]`

Here `_b` means binary representation. But that value is `3.403201383*10^38`, which is different from `3.402823669*10^38`, which is `(1.0)_b*2^[(11111111)_b-127]` and given by for example `c++` `<limits>`. Isn't 
`(1.11111111111111111111111)_b*2^[(11111111)_b-127]` representable and larger in the framework?

Does anybody know why?

Thank you.

Comment: Better suited for: https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The exponent 11111111<sub>b</sub> is reserved for infinities and NaNs, so your number cannot be represented.

The greatest value that can be represented in single precision, approximately 3.4028235×10<sup>38</sup>, is actually 1.11111111111111111111111<sub>b</sub>×2<sup>11111110<sub>b</sub>-127</sup>.

See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format

Answer (score 2):

Being the "***m***" the mantissa and the "***e***" the exponent, the answer is:

[image: ((2 - 2^(-m) * 2^(2^(e-1))))/2]

In your case, if the number of bits on IEEE 754 are:

- **16 Bits** you have 1 for the sign, 5 for the exponent and 10 for the mantissa. The largest number represented is 4,293,918,720.
- **32 Bits** you have 1 for the sign, 8 for the exponent and 23 for the mantissa. The largest number represented is 3.402823466E38
- **64 Bits** you have 1 for the sign, 11 for the exponent and 52 for the mantissa. The largest number represented is 2<sup>1024</sup> - 2<sup>971</sup>